# Synchronize MediaWiki with Gollum

Tags: jenkins, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, gollum-wiki

I would like to synchronize (bidirectional) selected pages of a corporate wiki ([MediaWiki](https://mediawiki.org)) with my personal wiki ([Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum)).

Server:

- 'vanilla' installation of MediaWiki
- [SyntaxHighlight GeSHi extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3ASyntaxHighlight_GeSHi) installed

Workstation packages:

- Jenkins
- [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)
- Pygments
- wikicloth, rdiscount, and asciidoc/asciidoctor

Functionality:

- synch pages and images
- preserving syntax highlighting, if possible

What are some options for doing so?

Comment: Why is the personal wiki forced to be on gollum?